# How to run .exe file on startup on gcp windows instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am having a VM, windows instance (GCE) on google cloud platform. I want to run a program(.exe) every time at the start of the instance.

I am able to run the file by putting it in the startup folder. but I want to run it using startup script as suggested by google here: [running startup scripts on a google compute engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript)

Answer (score 2):

To run `.exe` on GCP when **Windows** VM instance start/restart.

1. Click edit on VM instance
2. Expand Management, security, disks, networking, sole tenancy section
3. In the **Metadata** section, provide `windows-startup-script-cmd` as the metadata key.
4. In the **Value** box, provide `/path/to/exe-file`

Comment: Thankyou Gautam for your Reply, but i am still not able to run startup script. I created a text file as temp.txt and saved it in C Drive. Then i edited my VM instance with following values: In the Metadata section i provided "windows-startup-script-cmd" as the metadata key and in the value field i provided "C:/temp.txt"

Comment: @manoj sakhwar This guide above is for `.exe` files. You **can't** run `.txt` files even if you try to do it inside your VM directly. `.txt` is a text file and it's not executable. You should use `.exe` file to be able to run it and it'll be something like `C:\temp.exe`.

Comment: @manojsakhwar `.txt` files are not executable and no need to create a sperate file for that. `windows-startup-script-cmd` metadata value should be list of windows executable cmd. For example `windows-startup-script-cmd` = `/path/to/exe-file`. Also you can mention multiple cmd as a value.